# How to find out if clicking on an element will lead to a new page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which is as follows:

```
 <div id="toGoogle" onclick="window.location='https://www.google.com">Go to google</div>
```

Clicking on this link takes me to a website (in this case google.com).

(Ofcourse this click method could have been in JS file rather than being inline.)

Now I want to find out all such elements in my webpage which on clicking will lead to another page. I want to find out those page's URLs as well and print them to console.

Is it achievable using JS/Jquery?

Comment: It is impossible... there is no way to know if code is not inline.

Comment: You could go recursively down the DOM and analyse each object for hrefs and onclicks and then add them to a list.

Comment: @arlyon And when the onclick is attached unobtrusively? Not going to happen.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to be able to catch all possible outgoing links, but it may be possible if those outgoing links are all set in certain way (Or just a few of them). Is it the case?

Comment: Once the document is loaded the js will apply the attributes no?

Or maybe I am misinterpreting the question. Are you wanting to do this on raw html files or on an already loaded page?

Comment: @arlyon on a loaded page. On someone elses website.

Comment: you could (theoretically) implement a simulator - e.g. using technologies used for e2e / automated testing that clicks on each element of the dom and sees if the location changes afterwards - of course this seems ridiculous and i don't recommend doing it

Comment: Have a look at this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uvydkoyv/13/

Comment: @arlyon Yes. That would work for inlines and <a> tags. Thanks.

Comment: It searches every tag in the document for onlicks and hrefs. You can set up a regex to match urls as well.

Answer (score 1):

On a fully loaded page you can recursively traverse the DOM searching for onClick and href attributes. See the jsfiddle here for an example (and look at the log).

```
var walkDOM = function(node) {
  try {
    if (node.getAttribute("onClick") != null) {
      console.log(node.getAttribute("onClick"))
    }
    if (node.getAttribute("href") != null) {
      console.log(node.getAttribute("href"))
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("endpoint")
  }
  node = node.firstChild;
  while (node) {
    walkDOM(node);
    node = node.nextSibling;
  }
};

var fb = document.getElementById('facebook')
fb.setAttribute("onclick", "console.log('click')")

var yt = document.getElementById('youtube')
yt.setAttribute("href", "www.youtube.com")

walkDOM(document.documentElement);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/26wh7zeL/9/

You can then do a regex match for urls if you want.

Comment: This won't work on an `addEventListener` with `window.open` inside.

Comment: Yes this assumes that whatever url you're looking for ends up attached to the object. If you come up with a easy solution for this I'll edit my answer (or just submit it too) but I can't think of anything that isn't suddenly much more complicated.